# hotkey to navigate forward

Tags: notepad++

is there hotkey doing navigate forward ?  (like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>-</kbd> in VS2008)

I was not able to find it at the  'setting -> shortcut mapper'

notepad++ is very good software, i believe  notepad++ have the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Change Markers](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central)--I think this is what you are looking for, or at least can address some subset of it.

Answer (score 10):

Change Markers is no longer considered "Stable", and is unavailable in the Plugin Manager.

[Location Navigate (LocationNav)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/locationnav/) has hotkeys for moving backwards/forwards across both cursor positions and across source edits.

Comment: +1 thanks for the update. To help others, this uses CTRL + - to navigate backwards and CTRL + SHIFT - to navigate forwards. These keys can be changed under Settings ->Shortcut mapper -> Plugin commands -> Previous Location / Next Location

Comment: So far, "Location Navigate" is perfect! The only issue to note is that I had to install it manually, it would not download through plugin manager

Comment: @Tao Worked for me through Plugin Manager in latest version. (7.2.2)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend installing [OpenCTags plugin for Notepad++](http://openctags.sourceforge.net/). It relies on CTags that you can download too from its page.  At first usage (pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> for jumpnig to a symbol like function name), CTags will be invoked for building tags DB.
When you jump to symbol, OpenCTags keeps history.  Then, you can use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for going back and forward (= Previous and Next).
You can also, find all its commands in `Notepad++`'s plugin menu under OpenCTags.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the plugin "Location Navigate". It does support customizing shortcuts in 'setting -> shortcut mapper'.